# Selecting first row of each index in multi indexing pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

choose every first row of each index of multiindexing pandas dataframe.

```py
grouped = ecommerce[["category_id", "brand", "price"]].groupby(by=["category_id", "brand"]).mean()
grouped_sort = grouped.sort_values(by=["category_id", "price"], ascending=False)
```

`grouped_sort` looks like this:
[image: grouped_sort]

now on this data frame I want to choose in each category just the first brands with the highest price.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please post sample input and expected output `df` as text so we can copy paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can help:

```py
gsgb = grouped_sort.copy()
gsgb = gsgb.groupby(level=0)
print(type(gsgb))
gsgb.head()

for cat, df in gsgb:
    display(df.sort_values(by=["price"], ascending=False).reset_index().iloc[0])
```

**Working:**
It basically loops over all categories in the grouped dataframe and then sort values based on `price`, then reset index and finally choose the one with max price.

Comment: It's not work and raise error. error was: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). maybe it's happened because I use groupby in pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of `ecommerce`? So that I can use it to fine tune my answer?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/mkechinov/ecommerce-behavior-data-from-multi-category-store this is e-commerce dataset link

Comment: I have modified the code given the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try any of these methods:**

```
df.groupy(level=...).nth(0)

df.groupy(level=...).head(1)

df.groupy(level=...).first()
```

**NOTE: Please consider that .first() will reset the index and skip any rows containing *NaN*. Rows with *None* are not affected.